# Very general quartic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ has Picard group $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, k3-surfaces, picard-group

I am looking for a reference from which I can cite the following statement:

The Picard group of a very general quartic hypersurface $X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ is generated by the class of a hyperplane section.

What is the standard reference for this?

Comment: This is called the Noether-Lefschetz theorem. Modern proofs can be found in many places, e.g. in Voisin, Hodge theory and Complex AG II

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the Noether-Lefschetz theorem. Searching online should find plenty of results in web pages and lecture notes. If you want a published source, how about: Mark Green, *A new proof of the explicit Noether-Lefschetz theorem*, J. Differential Geom. 27 (1988), no. 1, 155–159.